# What's the sequence of using を and に

Tags: grammar

[image]

[image]

For example, when using the verb 置く. In my textbook(Genki) it shows that the usage of this verb is  "placeにobjectを置く"

In the case above, we first use  "place に" in front of "object を" to describe the motion of putting something.

However, for the verb 招待する, the book said: "personをeventに招待する"

Here I think that "event に" is also used for describing the verb 招待する. However, now the description comes after "person  を"

Thus, is it possible to have something like "objectをplaceに置く" For example スマホをここに置いて or "eventにpersonを招待する"　?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all make sense.

- ここにスマホを置いて
- スマホをここに置いて
- eventにpersonを招待する
- personをeventに招待する

Because ここに and スマホを both describe 置いて.
In the same way, eventに and personを both describe 招待する.
For example, these are correct Japanese.

- ここに置いて
- スマホを置いて

In like this case, Japanese don't care the order.

But if I had to differentiate the two, I choose "eventにpersonを招待する" when I'm talking about the event with someone. And when I'm talking about the person with someone, I choose "personをeventに招待する".

I think Japanese tend to say topic word first.